# Do online repositories of publicly traded companies' financial statements exist?

Tags: stocks, roth-ira, market-data, research

I'm currently managing my own Roth. I've made some stock purchases but I'd like to get much more in depth information and run my own top level research - even if it's not to the level of large financial institutions.

Companies release their financial statements quarterly, however, it isn't very efficient when you're trying to research various companies all at once and having to flip through various investor relations pages. That is what leads me to this question.

I'd appreciate any insight/guidance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Securities Exchange Commission's EDGAR search engine to search all available SEC related filings.

https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html

Top tip: use the fast search on the right to search for the company ticker rather than by company name.

Comment: Awesome - thanks! That is gold. Do you know of any non-government ones or are those typically only available through investment firms who charge a fee?